# Spreadsheet with hyperlinks to another sheet based on variable criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I am using Excel 2021 and have created a spreadsheet for a youth hockey league.
The information in column I is determined from a drop down box. I have corresponding worksheets for every division listed in the drop down and want to create a hyperlink to the corresponding sheet. The hyperlink would be in column J and when a division is selected from the drop down in column I, a Go Here link shows in J that can be clicked and takes you to the corresponding worksheet in the same workbook. The issue I am having is that the information in column I changes so I need the hyperlink to match whatever is selected and go to the worksheet with the same name. I can create a hyperlink but don't know how to create it for variable data. Should I be using a Match statement or If statements. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Should be like this in cell `J2` --> `=HYPERLINK("#'"&I2&"'!A1","Go Here")` where `I2` is the dropdown with the youth division. When click on cell `J2` it will goto cell `A1` of that specific sheet selected in dropdown!

Comment: That is so slick. Works like a charm! Thanks Mayukh!

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, about the requirements, then you can use the following formula:

[image]

---

• If `HYPERLINK()` to specific sheets within the [same workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ck0-_h_iptQ6_3T7S?e=Uc9TVe), then:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'"&I2&"'!A1","Go Here")
```

---

• If `HYPERLINK()` to specific sheets within the same workbook, to specific ranges then:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'"&I3&"'!B3:D11","Go Here")
```

---